# Subscript on half-type in hlsl

Tags: shader, hlsl, subscript

I seem to be unable to crack this nut myself and after some googling where I came up blank I thought it were time to turn to the community looking for answers.

I have some code in a project I am working with, I will provide a quite simplified version but it should help me show the concept.

```
//hlsl code
...
ps_main(...) {
    half mask = function_calculating_mask_and_returning_half();
    half3 color = condition ? a_previously_defined_half3 : mask.rrr;
}
```

The last line here is what's confusing me, especially the `mask.rrr` what does it really do? as far as I understand it would return a `half3 (mask, mask, mask)` but I seem to get a really high value from it, if I change it to say `mask.r` or simply `mask` it give me a result with much lower values, (as far as I can tell).

Could it be that it does something like `half3(mask^3, mask^3, mask^3)`? Because that is how it seem when looking at the result.

Anyhow I am thankful for suggestions or explanations as to how the code work and what it means to subscript a `half` with `.rrr` and any reference to what subscripts are possible would be a neat Christmas present. :P

Comment: What is you target DX and shader model version? This shader works as it should?

Comment: I am actually a bit new to `hlsl` in particular and the renderer utilizing it in general. But it targets DX9 and up. It does work and it seem to do what is expected, the only thing is that this `color` is used in a deferred stage to colorize specularity and when I use `mask.rrr` I get a super-high specularity which is why I am suspecting that the `mask.rrr` does something like a multiply of the value. So the main failing part is my understanding the `mask.rrr` subscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HLSL scalar types such as `float` and `half` are one-dimensional vectors which have the only `.x` (or the `.r`) component. This subscription is usually used for the type-casting:

```
float s = .5;
float3 v1 = s.xxx; // v is (0.5, 0.5, 0.5), or even
float3 v2 = 0.5.xxx; // :)
```

There's also an implicit conversions from vectors to scalars that takes the first component. Remember that components are stored like **RGBA** (or **XYZW**):

```
float3 v = {0.5, 0.6, 0.7}
float s1 = v; // s1 is 0.5 (implicit conversion)
float s2 = v.x // s2 is 0.5 (explicit conversion)
float s3 = v.xxx /* s3 is 0.5 because we've just created float3(v.x, v.x, v.x) 
                    and then implicitly taken it's X component, which is v.x */
```

This is how it works. Try to modify your code:

```
half3 color = condition ? a_previously_defined_half3 : half3(mask, mask, mask)
```

Nothing should change.

Comment: You are correct, of course, and I am glad to get it cleared. I have worked in similar languages, but am far from an expert. As you probably would suspect the reason for my results would soon prove to have nothing to do with the `.xxx` part, but it were in fact using a spectacular equation which I thought it weren't using so I guess it all boils down to my lacking knowledge in `hlsl` in general along with a misunderstanding of the code. I got it working as expected, and I marked your answer solves my question because I now really understand how that part works. Thanks!